# Fail to open up Scrapy on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I've been getting error bringing up Scrapy on my Linux box. I'm using Ubuntu 14.0 Desktop. I've installed setuptools and scrapy. For some reason when I put

```
scrapy --version
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 20, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/bench.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.tests.spiders import FollowAllSpider
ImportError: No module named tests.spiders
```

Any Idea what would this be from?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25218633/190597

Comment: I just installed scrapy from the ubuntu 13.x apt repository and it crashes on `scrapy --version` with a different error. This project is not well maintained.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson- Well I found the solution. I'll post it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with build 0.24.3 commited on Github.
To solve your problem just type this in terminal:

```
sudo pip install scrapy --upgrade
```

This will upgrade your version of Scrapy to 0.24.4.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the  [stackoverflow.com/q/25218633/190597](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25218633/190597). That will fix the issue. Or at least in my case.
Try uninstalling the old version of scrapy with:

```
pip uninstall Scrapy
```

and then installing it again using pip with this command:

```
pip install scrapy==0.24.2
```

well do not forget to install python development packages beforehand. That will raise another issue if not installed properly.